# Android develop LCD font

Tags: android, fonts

How to add additional font in android environment? I need to make a font like LCD with pale background numbers like this:

http://www.androidfreeware.net/img2/gps_speedometer_android_1.png

Comment: You may want to consider that commercial fonts probably require a license before embedding them in your own app.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public void setFontTextView(Context c, TextView name) {
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),"fonts/Arial.ttf");
name.setTypeface(font);
}
```

Download Arial font in ttf file formate and put in asset folder. Thats enough.

Comment: clarification: according to your example, the developer should put Arial.ttf within assets/fonts

Answer (score 35):

We at [bangalore android developers group](http://www.meetup.com/The-Bangalore-Android-Group/) had done this for one of our project [AutoMeter](http://github.com/the100rabh/AutoMeter) You can have a look at the code there in detail.

The code would look something like this

```
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"DS-DIGIB.TTF");
waitingTimeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.WaitingTime);
waitingTimeView.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

DS-DIGIB.TTF is the font put in the assets folder

Comment: Does adding a hindi font work for you? I am trying to add a font like you did. But it fails with NPE.

Comment: if its ttf it should ideally work, though I never tried it. Could share the font somewhere ??

Answer (score 6):

You want to use the [android.graphics.Typeface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) class, which can create new Typefaces from assets or files.