# Android Menuitem Font change

Tags: android

I need to apply custom font in to MenuItem. Is it possible to apply custom font in to MenuItem?

I'm relay appreciate you any comment.

Chandana

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the font on the TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888508/how-to-change-the-font-on-the-textview)