# Android TextView display phonetic(IPA) symbols?

Tags: java, android, character-encoding

For example I've java string with [bɪ’fɔ:l] word.
Set this string to TextView by .setTest method and it displays as [b[]f[]l] where [] is squear symbol.
I've tried .getText from the TextView, but java string contains the same right symbols.

WebView gave the same result.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square symbols means that the font you are using (Droid sans in android by default) has not defined the character you need to display.

To change the font take a look at this question: [How to change the font on the TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888508/how-to-change-the-font-on-the-text-view-in-android) and use a font that can show the special characters you need