# How to set Font for TextView in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to change the font on the text view in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888508/how-to-change-the-font-on-the-text-view-in-android)

I tried a lot to set font for the TextView in my app. But there is no way seems to set font in android. I want to set Arial font for all of my TextView through xml. I added Arial.ttf to my assets still unable to set style in xml. Please find me a way out.

Comment: Here is a similar Question/Answer that I think may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888508/how-to-change-the-font-on-the-text-view-in-android

Answer (score 23, accepted):

AFAIK you can't do it in xml, you have to do it in code:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/Arial.otf");
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CustomFontText);
tv.setTypeface(tf)
```