# How to set a font for specific textview in Android?

Tags: android

I followed the steps from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271396/how-to-set-font-for-textview-in-android) and it crashes my app when running.
Below is my entire code.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/myriad_pro_regular.ttf");
        tx.setTypeface(tf);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

When I add the below codes

```
TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/myriad_pro_regular.ttf");
tx.setTypeface(tf);
```

The app crashes and I have no idea what I did wrong here.

Comment: add log please!

Comment: put your crash logs .

Comment: Try to use android studio 3.0+ they have simplified the use of font and downloadable font

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set content view after you initialized textView. This should be correct approach:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
Typeface tf = 
Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/myriad_pro_regular.ttf");
tx.setTypeface(tf);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first put your text view initialization under `setContentView`.

This is working code

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(),"myriad_pro_regular.ttf");
        tx.setTypeface(tf);

    }
```