# How to show telugu font in emulator correctly

Tags: android, unicode

I am developing an application in which I get the unicode using json and it showing the unicode correctly when I am trying to see in the debug mode, Now the problem is that how can I show in the emulator, I have using the UTF-8 for rendering the unicode but it didn't show?

And when I am trying to show in using the setTypeface it showing the Telugu font in a simple program even but not correctly. I am using the Pothana2000.ttf to convert the telugu unicode to Telugu language.

Comment: Hey I think Telgu font is not predefine for emulater and also for device.
So you have to add custom. For installing font see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487976/what-is-the-best-way-of-installing-new-font-to-android-emulator/10487991#10487991) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926263/add-custom-font-for-complete-android-application)