# What is the best way of installing new font to android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-fonts

I know there are many questions regarding font installation on android emulator. I'm sharing the method that worked for me as an answer, if anyone have a better way please share it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever android fails to find a specific character it looks to `DroidSansFallback.ttf`, so what you need to do is replace the `DroidSansFallback.ttf` of the emulator by renaming a ttf font of your required language to `DroidSansFallback.ttf`. Do the following steps.

> 1.Get a market enabled rooted android emulator. You can find one here: [Rooted Market Enabled AVD](http://www.ehalm.at/avd-2.2-market.php?l=en)
>
> 2.Then grab an explorer app, I prefer root explorer.
>
> 3.Rename a free ttf font(which you want to install) to DroidSansFallback.ttf.
>
> 4.Create an AVD from the image you downloaded in step 1.
>
> 5. Push DroidSansFallback.ttf to the sdcard of emulator via file explorer in DDMS (I'm using Eclipse Indigo IDE).
> 6. Install root explorer (you can use another explorer downloaded via market).
> 7. Open root explorer, click mount r/w.
> 8. Then go to sd card and copy DroidSansFallback.ttf, then go to system, click mount r/w.
>
> 9.Then go to fonts and overwrite the existing DroidSansFallback.ttf.
>
> 10. Then give all permissions to the new DroidSansFallback.ttf from permissions option.

That's it.
I used this method to answer a question about [Bangla Font Insatallation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369552/how-to-install-bangla-on-android-emulator/10369560#10369560)

Comment: Imran, is there a single .tff that supports major Indian languages? If yes, what is it called?

Comment: @JaVAndroid if there is no single ttf supporting major Indian languages you can use different fonts in a single text. Take a look at my answer here: [Multiple TypeFace in single TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675070/multiple-typeface-in-single-textview/10740758#10740758)