# Multiple TypeFace in single TextView

Tags: java, android

I want to set the first character on `TextView` with a `TypeFace` and the second character with a different Type face and so on.
I read this example:

```
Spannable str = (Spannable) textView.getText();
str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.ITALIC), 0, 7  
                             ,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

but it didn't help me, because I want to set multiple `TypeFace (external TTFs)`
Any idea??

Comment: Say you have two typeface like `Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "1.ttf"); Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "2.ttf");` then, `SpannableStringBuilder SS = new SpannableStringBuilder("your_text"); SS.setSpan ( new StyleSpan(font2.getStyle()), 0, 2,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); SS.setSpan ( new StyleSpan(font.getStyle()), 3, 6,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);`. Have you tried this approach?

Comment: I tried it, but didn't work, I think font1.getStyle() get the style of font not the font itself

Comment: I got the solution to your problem, take a look at my answer :).

Answer (score 129, accepted):

### Use the following code:(I'm using Bangla and Tamil font)

```
  TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_fonts);  
        txt.setTextSize(30);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Akshar.ttf");
        Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "bangla.ttf");   
        SpannableStringBuilder SS = new SpannableStringBuilder("আমারநல்வரவு");
        SS.setSpan (new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font2), 0, 4,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        SS.setSpan (new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font), 4, 11,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        txt.setText(SS);
```

---

The outcome is:

[image]

---

This uses the `CustomTypefaceSpan` class, taken from [How can I use TypefaceSpan or StyleSpan with a custom Typeface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819049/how-can-i-use-typefacespan-or-stylespan-with-custom-typeface):

---

```
package my.app;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.TypefaceSpan;

public class CustomTypefaceSpan extends TypefaceSpan {

private final Typeface newType;

public CustomTypefaceSpan(String family, Typeface type) {
    super(family);
    newType = type;
}

@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
    applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType);
}

@Override
public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
    applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType);
}

private static void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
    int oldStyle;
    Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
    if (old == null) {
        oldStyle = 0;
    } else {
        oldStyle = old.getStyle();
    }

    int fake = oldStyle & ~tf.getStyle();
    if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
    }

    if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
        paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
    }

    paint.setTypeface(tf);
}
}
```

---

Comment: Is worth to specify that this code doesn't work if you have `android:textAllCaps="true"` in your layout.

Answer (score 2):

**Kotlin developers** can use this to use two or more typeface for single button or textview.

**1. Copy and Paste this class:**

```
class CustomTypefaceSpan(family: String?, private val newType: Typeface) : TypefaceSpan(family) {

    override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType)
    }

    override fun updateMeasureState(paint: TextPaint) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType)
    }

    companion object {
        private fun applyCustomTypeFace(paint: Paint, tf: Typeface) {
            val oldStyle: Int
            val old = paint.typeface
            oldStyle = old?.style ?: 0
            val fake = oldStyle and tf.style.inv()
            if (fake and Typeface.BOLD != 0) {
                paint.isFakeBoldText = true
            }
            if (fake and Typeface.ITALIC != 0) {
                paint.textSkewX = -0.25f
            }
            paint.typeface = tf
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Using this by:**

```
val buttonText = "Get it for 100 Points"

//making text yellow
    buttonText.setSpan(
        ForegroundColorSpan(
            ContextCompat.getColor(
                this, R.color.yellow_FFC001
            )
        ),
        11, 14,
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )

//changing text size of yellow portion i.e. "100"
    val sp20 = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.sp_20)
    buttonText.setSpan(AbsoluteSizeSpan(sp20), 11, 14, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)

//setting button fonts
    buttonText.setSpan(
        CustomTypefaceSpan("", ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.roboto_condensed_bold)!!),
        0,
        buttonText.length,
        0
    )

//finally setting this text to my button
btGetPoints.text = buttonText
```

**3. And the final output would be like this**

[image]