# Using custom font for part of a Text

Tags: android, fonts, spannablestring

```
Typeface robotoBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),
        "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
Typeface robotoLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),
        "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");


SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("This must be BOLd\nThis must be NORMAL");
sb.setSpan(robotoBold, 0, 17, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
sb.setSpan(robotoLight, 18, 37, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
mTextView.setText(sb);
```

This gives me a normal text for the whole TextView.

Thank You.

Comment: see this post may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675070/multiple-typeface-in-single-textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are able to do this functionality

**font for part of a Text**

you have to use alter net like take two textview and divide your text and set that text.

or use

spannable text

Comment: "We are not able to do this functionality".  Oh yes we are.

Comment: @Simon i also address spannable text if you have answer then give answer.

Comment: The answer has already been given.  But I see what you mean.  However, the statement is incorrect.  Spannable text is perfectly able to do this.

Answer (score -3):

```
mTextView.setText("This must be BOLd\nThis must be NORMAL");
Spannable span = new SpannableString(mTextView.getText());
span.setSpan(robotoBold,0,17,Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
span.setSpan(robotoLight,18,37,Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
mTextView.setText(span);
```

Comment: Otherwiseuse this mTextView.setText("This must be BOLd\nThis must be NORMAL");
Spannable span = new SpannableString(mTextView.getText());
span.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.2f),0,17,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
span.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.6f),18,37,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);mTextView.setText(span);