# Android : Change Typeface of Edit Text for new text that is entered

Tags: android, android-typeface

I want to have different typefaces for different parts of text in the same Edit Text. I have tried doing this to change Typeface :

```
Typeface myFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "droid-sans.ttf");
myEditText.setTypeface(myFont, Typeface.BOLD);
```

I am using a button to make text BOLD.

But this changes Typeface of the entire text that is already present in the EditText ! I want to keep existing text formatting and change Typeface for the text that will be entered after I click "Bold" button.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227670/using-custom-font-for-part-of-a-text

Comment: That would not be a solution if we want to change TypeFace at runtime. Typeface should be applied to the text at runtime as user types into EditText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) interface. You can use this to change the font of different part of an EditText or TextView.

This is an example code for you to turn a selected text into ITALIC.

```
Spannable str = mBodyText.getText(); 
if(mBodyText.getSelectionEnd() > mBodyText.getSelectionStart()) 
  str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.ITALIC),  
                      mBodyText.getSelectionStart(), mBodyText.getSelectionEnd(),  
                      Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
else
  str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.ITALIC),
              mBodyText.getSelectionEnd(),
              mBodyText.getSelectionStart(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: Would you please explain me, how can i use this to change typeface "on the fly". If i press Bold button, text that will be typed after pressing the button should get bold. You are processing selected text.

Comment: BTW i figured out the way to do that. Your answer works. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @pg18 consider telling **what you figured out** in the answer or comment !