# Put in bold some parts of a TextView?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a TextView inside which, I wrote of the questions and answers. If I now want to put in bold only the questions as I do? There maybe some code that gives you the ability to put in bold text character 0-10 for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this way

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("MyText<b>MyBoldText</b>"));
```

Output shall be like this "MyText**MyBoldText**"

and you can also do this using string

```
<string name="myMixedText">My simple Text<b>My Bold Text<i>MyBoldItalicText</i></b></string>
```

now

```
textView.setText(R.string.myMixedText);
```

Output shall be like this "My simple Text**My Bold Text*MyBoldItalicText***"

Comment: Many Thanks, it work! I put the characters <b> in strings.xml and then the TextView (xml) I put android: text = "@ string / name".

Comment: @MariocciRossini yes this will also works on xml layout file and if it helps then rate and accept it

Answer (score 1):

Your question has been answered here :

[Multiple TypeFace in single TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675070/multiple-typeface-in-single-textview)

Just add the CustomTypefaceSpan class, and use Typeface.BOLD and any other font you want to use.