# Android: TextView with multiples colors and fonts

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

Ok, so I gather that this should be a fairly straightforward process.

I've read the following questions:

- [Multiple Typefaces in the same TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036685/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-typefaces-in-the-same-textview?rq=1)
- [Multiple Typefaces in the same TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675070/multiple-typeface-in-single-textview)
- [Put in bold some parts of a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940327/put-in-bold-some-parts-of-a-textview?rq=1)
- [Making part of a string bold in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850822/making-part-of-a-string-bold-in-textview?lq=1)

The advice seems to be pretty similar across all of these questions and answers. I'm trying to avoid the HTML techniques and use `SpannableString` and `SpannableStringBuilder` instead. Ultimately, I'd like to be able to use multiple different typefaces in a single TextView, but for now, I'd just like to figure out how to get multiple colors working.

I'm trying to implement those techniques in this way:

```
// Get a typeface for my custom font
String regularFontPath          = "fonts/Abel-Regular.ttf";
Typeface regularTf              = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), regularFontPath);

// Set the label's typeface (this part is working)
mItemCodesLabel.setTypeface(regularTf);

// Create a spannable builder to build up my
// TextView's content from data
SpannableStringBuilder builder  = new SpannableStringBuilder();

// These colors are defined and working well in other parts of my app
ForegroundColorSpan ltGraySpan  = new ForegroundColorSpan(R.color.light_gray);
ForegroundColorSpan dkGraySpan  = new ForegroundColorSpan(R.color.dark_gray);

// mCodesList has good data and the actual data output from this
// loop is correct. Just the styling is wrong
for (int i = 0; i < mCodesList.size(); i = i + 1) {
    ParseObject code            = mCodesList.get(i);
    String value                = code.getString("value") + " | ";
    if (i > 0) {
        // I want new codes to be on a new line (this works)
        value                   = "\n" + value;
    }
    SpannableString valueSpan   = new SpannableString(value);
    valueSpan.setSpan(ltGraySpan, 0, value.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    builder.append(valueSpan);

    String loc                  = code.getString("location");
    SpannableString locSpan     = new SpannableString(loc);
    locSpan.setSpan(dkGraySpan, 0, loc.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    builder.append(locSpan);
}
mItemCodesLabel.setText(builder);
```

The net result is that the `TextView` contains the correct text contents. The `TextView` is the correct typeface. But the entire contents of the `TextView` are my `@color/light_gray` color. I'm not sure why, because in the XML layout file, I **had** specified my `@color/dark_gray` color (which I expect to be overridden by setting the text with a `Spannable`). Even if I change both `ForegroundColorSpan` objects to use `R.color.dark_gray`, the `TextView` still comes out light gray. I don't see anywhere else in my code where I'm setting the color of the text, so I'm really at a loss.

I'm running this on an LG Optimus G Pro, which is running 4.4.2. I have another `TextView` where I need to get multiple colors and font working and even underline some parts of the text, so this is a pretty big deal for me. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Just a comment here: https://gist.github.com/Trikke/90efd4432fc09aaadf3e comes really handy in those situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `getResource().getColor(R.color.light_gray)` to retrieve the color you are passing to the `ForegroundColorSpan`. I doubt it is retrieving it internally for you. You probably need to instantiate a new `ForegroundColorSpan` at every iteration. It is not possible to reuse it

Comment: If that really is the answer, I'm going to beat my head against the wall! ;-) I'll give that a shot and get back to you. Thanks for answering. Why does it let me use that syntax if that syntax won't actually work?

Comment: the method takes an int and both the colour and the id of the colour are int

Comment: Well, at least this was a big enough frustration that I will have learned this lesson once and for all! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: After checking this out, it works beautifully! Thanks! I also learned (the hard way) that you have to create a new *Span object for each section you wish to customize. If you try to reuse *Span objects, it would appear that only the last application "sticks". Gahh!

Comment: I am glad it worked out. Look at the bright side, next time you'll *probably* not do the same mistake

Answer (score 2):

You may Use SpannableStringBuilder because it implements from spannable and CharSequence, also you may do anything with following

```
TextView txtTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
String text = "This is an example";    
final SpannableStringBuilder str = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
str.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan("monospace"), 0, 8, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
str.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan("serif"), 9, 12, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.white)), 0, 5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey)), 6, 8, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
str.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
txtTest.setText(str);
```

I have add colors.xml in values

```
<color name="black">#000000</color>
<color name="grey">#DCDCDC</color>
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
```

Comment: At the very least *tailor your answer to the question*. You are not addressing the issues in this question at all.