# How to Display Telugu Fonts corectly in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

Hi folks i want to display data in Telugu.

```
Typeface Telugu;
Telugu = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Tikkana.ttf");
TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label);
tt.setTypeface(Telugu);
```

Am Not getting properly can any one help me please find the image some content showing correctly some is not showing correctly am getting the data from Client RssFeed....please reply

Comment: Telegu will be displayed where you are using the **Telegu Typeface** ( like it will be shown in the **tt** TextView) but not in a place where you don't have the font set. You need to install **Telegu font** to the system by replacing **DroidSansFallback.ttf**(requires root permission) to watch Telegu everywhere. If you are interested check this [Font installation in emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487976/what-is-the-best-way-of-installing-new-font-to-android-emulator/10487991#10487991)

Comment: By the way... It's Telugu.. NOT Telegu. :-)