# Unicode characters on Android

Tags: android, unicode

I have developed Android applications before. I plan to write an Android application that will support the gujarati language with Unicode. http://developer.android.com/index.html does not provide any hint on the topic. The `android.textview` class does not contain a language option for languages, does adding fonts in the asset directory help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can set custom font to the **TextView**.

---

Assuming you have a **gujarati.ttf** font in **fonts** folder under **assets** folder:

### Code for setting custom font to TextView:

```
 Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/gujarati.ttf");               
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CustomFontText);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

---

It enables gujarati only for the TextView for which you have set the font, but if you want to show gujarati system wide then you need to know:

> Whenever android fails to find a specific character it looks to
> DroidSansFallback.ttf, so what you need to do is replace the
> DroidSansFallback.ttf of the emulator/mobile by renaming a gujarati ttf font to
> DroidSansFallback.ttf

---

Here is the process if you want to [install gujarati font in android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487976/what-is-the-best-way-of-installing-new-font-to-android-emulator/10487991#10487991).