# Android: set application-wide font

Tags: android, fonts

I have to use custom fonts in my application. I know how to read a font from the assets directory and apply them to a control, however this seems a very laborious task.

Is there anyway I can apply a custom font from my assets directory to all the controls in the application.

Comment: Here the answer for your question... write an customtextview extends the Textview class with specific font style as follows.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926263/add-custom-font-for-complete-android-application

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is: Make custom textViews, by extending them, and then use them in your xml layouts. You will have to override `setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style)` method for that. You may want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-font-for-entire-application)

Comment: Thanks this is what i am doing. Is it possible that i can add the attributes from XML. I have a class that extends EditText. Now from the XML i want add a new attribute, say myfontFace="arial" and in the class i want to read the value of the xml, is that even possible.

Comment: If you are talking about custom xmls then you might consider it keeping in res/raw and access it through `R` object. Else if you are talking about getting values from just xmls, put them into res/values/string.xml and you can access them through the `R` object

Answer (score 0):

Try this

If from your asset folder

```
Typeface.createFromAsset(yourAssetManager, pathOfYourFontAsset);
```

If externally

```
Typeface.createFromFile(path)
```