# Special characters in a TextView

Tags: android, character, textview

I want to show the **"♫"** character in an Android TextView, but it shows [] instead.

This is my code:

```
txtCatname.setText("♫");
```

How can I display this symbol correctly?

Comment: This means that the font lacks this particular Unicode glyph. Use a different font.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use an Unicode code: http://unicode-table.com/en/.

Such as:

```
txtCatname.setText("\u266b");
```

or alternatively use an iconic font, such as font awesome:
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Use this alternative (or any other iconic font  you like), in case this character isn't supported (not all Unicode characters are supported).

Comment: One notice. In strings.xml the only way is to use html codes of chars
i.e. for \u266B equivalent is &#9835; so define `<string name="note">&#9835;</string>`

Comment: hi bro how can add this character "

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
String str = "♫";
byte spbyte[] = str.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
str = new String( spbyte,"UTF-8");
txtCatname.setText(str);
```

If it doesn't work, try this:

```
String str = "♫";
txtCatname.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```

Comment: .setText(Html.fromHtml(str));

This part makes your answer the best one. At least for my case!

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else helps, you can either:

1. use a custom font (e.g. 
   http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_fonts.htm or [Add custom font for complete android application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6926263/755804) )
   or
2. add an image:
   [How to add image in a TextView text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352496/how-to-add-image-in-a-textview-text/21250752#21250752)

Answer (score 1):

That is common when the source file is encoded as ANSI. Converting the source file as UTF-8 (without BOM) will likely solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This seems pretty simple now:

- Simply go to [unicode list](https://unicode-table.com/en/#00A9)
  and choose your unicode and copy go it.
- Go to strings.xml and paste it.
  [image]
  This will paste the unicode character instead of it's code and use it in your xml as a normal string.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply append the symbol as a string in your string.xml
By adding double quotes to the special character.