# How to write the Bitcoin logo as text?

Tags: android, unicode, textview

I am developing an android app and I want to write the Bitcoin symbol in a TextView.
Is there any code for that like "\u20B9" for Rupees?

[image: bitcoin symbol]

Comment: have you tried \u20BF as this is the suggested bitcoin symbol.

Comment: try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23608552/8867002) for unicodes

Comment: yes . i tried but its not working @TentenPonce

Comment: @nileshprajapati Please check the answer given below and let me know if it is working for you.

Comment: can anyone tell me whats wrong in this question why vote down (-1) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android supports `Bitcoin` Unicode symbol since `Android O`, you can read more about it from this [link](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_symbol). Just try to run your code in `Android O` and I'm sure that everything will be fine.

But if still want to use `TextView`, to show `BTC` symbol, consider [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com), it's actually designed for `WEB`, but it also possible to use in Android.

1. [Download](https://fontawesome.com/) icons pack.
2. Put `ttf` font file to your `assets` folder
3. Then get `Typeface` object and set it to your `TextView`:

   ```
   String fontName = "fa-brands-400.ttf";
   Typeface fontAwesome = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/" + fontName);
   textView.setTypeface(fontAwesome);
   ```
4. Add string `XML` resource with `FontAwesome` code point of `BTC` symbol:

   ```
   <string name="btc_fa">&#xf15a;</string>
   ```
5. Set this string to `TextView`:

   ```
   textView.setText(R.string.btc_fa);
   ```

As the result, you will get this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a string in `strings.xml` like the following one:

```
<string name="bitCoin">\u20BF</string>
```

Use the following to create the textView with BitCoin Symbol:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/bitCoin"/>
```

You will have your bitcoin symbol in textView like below

[image]

Comment: this is a hack not a real answer

Comment: @matrix have u tried to implement it? Please take some time and implement as described above and you will get the bitcoin symbol on android.

Comment: I didnt say it does not work. I just said that you shouldn't create strings just to translate some unicode

Comment: @matrix Ya true indeed. We shouldn't but It will can cater the needs till we find the optimum solution for the problem.

Comment: just tried this, it works. But I'm not sure if it'll show OK on all target devices.