# How to write `@` symbol in android TextView at starting

Tags: android, textview, symbols

I want to write text starting with `@` symbol in `TextView`. But, when I write it in both places as a hardcoded and using string resource, the error says `missing /`. When I type some characters before `@`, it works fine. But, I want to write it at the beginning. How to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608471/special-characters-android-textview

Comment: @deepakkumar The question you linked is about different character, but I want to write `@` symbol, for which, the IDE is treating as a resource telling character. I want it as a hard coded string.

Comment: The unicode for @ is \u0040 so all you have to do is mention it in your string tag like <string>\u0040Deepak Kumar</string>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add Unicode character in String.xml like

```
<string name="character">\u0040 character</string>
```

add this in your textview like :

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/character"/>
```

Here \u0040 indicates ' @ ' sign.

Answer (score 10):

Use it like this `\@`

```
<string name="character">\@ character</string>
```

Or you can use the Unicode character `\0040`

Answer (score 1):

Simply write "\@" as the error says ;) (it's a special character that need to be escaped with a "\")

Comment: but it will print both things like `/@`, I just want `@` at starting

Comment: Sorry it's the "\" character and not the "/', I edited my answer.