# is there a solve for setting text to : '<' in android studio?

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/uibackground"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/previousButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonstyles"
            android:text="<"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/textSwitcher"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonstyles"
            android:inAnimation="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
            android:outAnimation="@android:anim/slide_out_right" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonstyles"
            android:text=">"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

when i run app i get this error:
activity_main.xml:25: AAPT: error: not well-formed (invalid token).

i checked 25th line but, i couldn't see a problem. maybe it's because of '<' sign but i don't know. is there an alternative method to write this sign?

Comment: Hi, checkout this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608471/special-characters-in-a-textview

Comment: "&lt;" will help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `"<"` with `"&lt;"`
it should work

Here are more symbols to work with:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html