# Custom font not getting applied

Tags: java, android, fonts

My Custom Font class

```
public class CustomFontText extends TextView {
    /*
  * Caches typefaces based on their file path and name, so that they don't have to be created every time when they are referenced.
  */
    private static Typeface mTypeface;

    public CustomFontText(final Context context) {
        super(context, null);
    }

    public CustomFontText(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, 0);
        readAttrs(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomFontText(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        readAttrs(context, attrs);
    }

    private void readAttrs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextView);

        // Read the title and set it if any
        String fontName = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomTextView_fontname);
        if (fontName != null) {
            // We have a attribute value
            if (mTypeface == null) {
                mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontName);
                setTypeface(mTypeface);
            }
        }

        // a.recycle();
    }
}
```

Applying in XMl file

```
<somepackage.CustomFontText
            android:id="@+id/details"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ewfewfewqfewfwef"
            custom:fontname="Roboto-Regular.ttf" />
```

It is not giving any kind of error but I am not able to view any changes in the textview. Changing the fontname makes no difference.

Comment: check it this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926263/add-custom-font-for-complete-android-application

Comment: did you check if `fontName` is not null? Do you have the fonts in the assets?

Comment: @Blackbelt I have put all the fonts in my asset folder.And also I debug my code to check if it's null or not.

Comment: Just a hunch, but you could try moving the `setTypeface(mTypeface);` line outside the check for `mTypeface == null`.

Comment: @TR4Android It's working now.Thanks for the trick.Can you answer my question so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Soham Glad it's working now! I've posted the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the code `setTypeface(mTypeface);` outside the check for `mTypeface == null` should solve the issue. So the code should look like this:

```
if (mTypeface == null) {
    mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontName);
}
setTypeface(mTypeface);
```

This is because `mTypeface` is declared `static` and such all `CustomFontText` instances share the same typeface (which makes sense for caching). If `setTypeface` is called inside the check though, it will only get applied once, when the typeface is first loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't know why yours not working, however, alternatively you can use [Calligraphy by chrisjenx](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy). I used it in one of my projects and it works great!

Comment: I don't want to use can libraries.Some code tweaking would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Create folder **fonts** in the **assets** folder of your project and instead of using just the font name for **custom:fontname**, use the path to the file.

```
custom:fontname="fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add ttf or otf file in your assets folder.

**Create custom class extends with TextView**

```
public class CustomText extends TextView {

public CustomText (Context context) {
    super(context);
    createTextView(context, null);
}

public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    createTextView(context, attrs);
}


public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    createTextView(context, null);
}

private void createTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    String fontName;
    TypedArray typedArray;
    if (isInEditMode())
        return;
    if (attrs != null) {
        typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FontTypeFace, 0, 0);
        fontName = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.FontTypeFace_typeface);
        setFontTypeFace(context, fontName);
        typedArray.recycle();
    }
}

private void setFontTypeFace(Context context, String fontName) {
    if (fontName != null) {
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontName);
        setTypeface(typeface);
    }
}
}
```

**declare stylable in your attrs file :**

```
<declare-styleable name="FontTypeFace">
    <attr name="typeface" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

**Create control using custom textview in xml file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1">
 <com.Widget.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_text_size_12"
            app:typeface="@string/thin" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Just add the assets file name inside string.xml file**

```
<!--String for assets font type file name -->

<string name="bold">bold.otf</string>
<string name="light">light.otf</string>
<string name="medium">medium.otf</string>
<string name="regular">regular.otf</string>
<string name="regular_italic">regular_italic.otf</string>
<string name="semi_bold">semibold.otf</string>
<string name="thin">thin.otf</string>
```

Comment: What is Custom_TextView_typeface?