# How do I implement getview() for listview

Tags: java, android, listview, font-face

How do I implement getView() (how do i create getview() )for an already created listview (code below). so that I can change font of the textVIew items and further attribute stylig

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

String[] items = { "some", "fancy", "items", "to", "show" };

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.listitem, items);

 listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView 
  android:id="@+id/listView1" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**listview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:textSize="20sp"
android:padding="22dp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
/>
```

**changed MainActivity.java**

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   Context context;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
     String[]  items = { "some", "fance", "rock", "shot", "trance" };
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);




    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.genre_list, items);

    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);}
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row;

    if (null == convertView) {
         LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                 .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.genre_list, null);

    } else {

    row = convertView;

    }

    TextView tv = (TextView)row.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"roboto.ttf");  
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "font fetched!",  
         Toast.L  ENGTH_LONG).show();
    tv.setText(items[position]);
    tv.setTypeface(font);
    return row;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`getView()` is a method in Adapter classes, like ArrayAdapter and SimpleCursorAdapter. You must extend an Adapter class, in your case ArrayAdapter, to access `getView()`.

This [Google Talk](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) by Romain Guy, an Android lead programmer, discusses the best practices to extend an Adapter in great detail.

---

That said you can change the font and many other style attributes through XML, you don't necessarily need to create a custom Adapter.

- [How to change the font on the TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2888508/1267661)
- [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) and [`android:textAppearance`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textAppearance)

Comment: check changed MainActivity.java in my edit this does not work I don't think getView is being called

Comment: No, it is not being called. You **must** write a custom Adapter to use `getView()`. Please watch the video above, it describes how to do what you want and there is no reason for me to repeat its contents here. The video also demonstrates that the method your are trying to use can be improved with ViewHolders among other things.

Answer (score 0):

for Changing font for TextView you will need to create Custom ArrayAdapter. but you can do this by just overriding default getView method as :

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                                 "yourfontname.ttf");

listView1.setListAdapter(new 
              ArrayAdapter<string>(this,R.layout.listitem, items) {

@Override

public View getView(int position, View convertView, 
                                       ViewGroup parent) {

View row;

if (null == convertView) {

row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);

} else {

row = convertView;

}

TextView tv = (TextView)row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

tv.setText(items[position]);
tv.setTypeface(font);
return row;

}

});
```

Comment: i used the above getview() method inside my oncreate() and it tells me to remove @override annoatio so I did then it shows me the marker """The method getItem(int) is undefined for the type MainActivity""create method getItem(int)...... in this line tv.setText(getItem(position));

Comment: font does not change I don't think the getView() is called!!

Comment: @user1979237 : you are ding in wrong way do same as in my answer

Comment: check changed MainActivity.java in my edit this will give yoou the idea of my code

Comment: I get full blank white background and no list items :(... nothing in logacat

Comment: @user1979237 : means code is working plz edit your post with latest code