# How to change the colour of text in Android apps

Tags: java, android, styles

This question might be so so simple but difficult for me as a beginner.  I am developing an Android app by java. So There is a TextView.

How can I add some style to it. Like changing its colour, font and etc ??

Comment: Please describe what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will change the color from xml:

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height"wrap_content"
android:textColor="#123123"
/>
```

Changing font is a little bit more in depth. Put your desired font file into the assets folder of your project and use the `setTypeface()` method of TextView. That has been covered in a previous question: [How to change the font on the TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888508/how-to-change-the-font-on-the-textview)

Comment: Thanks. So are all styles added to its own section? Like isn't there something like CSS that you make a style identified by an id and that applies to all widgets that hold that id ?!

Comment: you can do something similar, see here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 0):

Alright, Here is the documentation of [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html). There are basically two ways to style the text view using xml and in java code. Here is the relevent xml attributes:

```
android:textColor
android:textColorHighlight
android:textColorHint
android:textSize
```

And so on. On code it would look something like this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```