# Android number text font.

Tags: android, fonts

So I have been seeking for font like this one:

[image]

And without any results. Can someone give me a hint where could I find this font for my Android application?

Comment: Look: https://www.google.com/#q=lcd+font

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few fonts you could use -

1. LED
2. Let's Go Digital Regular
3. Digital Readout (for text that looks like an LCD screen)

Download Links -

1. http://www.fontpalace.com/font-download/LED.Font/
2. http://www.fontspace.com/download/13974/c46cca08c1d746a1836e0080c24de5c2/wlm-fonts_lets-go-digital.zip
3. http://www.1001fonts.com/digital-readout-font.html

P.S. StackOverflow isn't a forum! You should typically do a lot of research before asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

try below code:-

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/Arial.otf");
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CustomFontText);
tv.setTypeface(tf)
```

download below font and put into your assets folder.

http://www.fontspace.com/category/lcd

[refer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888508/how-to-change-the-font-on-the-textview)

Comment: Good info . I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Download Arial font in ttf file formate and put in asset folder.you also use DS-DIGIB.TTF font file.

```
        public void setFontTextView(Context c, TextView name) {
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),"fonts/Arial.ttf");
        name.setTypeface(font);
        }
```