# Set different font by default for TextView in Android

Tags: android, fonts

I want to set a custom font by default for TextView in android app. Will i need to create custom view for this ? Or is there any other way to do it except for loading it from assets folder and applying them individually?

Is there a way that a custom font can be directly used in xml, just like "sans","serif"

Answer (score 0):

In your `asset` folder create a folder named `fonts` and then access it like this :

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview03);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/YourFile.otf");
text.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but i dont want to set them on each textview like this.

Answer (score 0):

First download the .ttf file of the font you need (urfont.ttf). Place it in the assets folder(Inside assest folder create new folder named "fonts" and place it inside it).

```
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
    "fonts/urcustomfont.ttf");
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CustomFontText);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has previously been answered:

[How to change the font on the TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888508/how-to-change-the-font-on-the-textview)

Default font is Droid Sans. Also can have Droid Sans Mono and Droid Serif. These can be changed through either using `setTypeface`, or through editing the `android:typeface` XML

As already stated, you can use custom fonts by the method described by [AndroidWarrior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2636938/androidwarrior) but keep in mind licensing issues as well as the performance of your app if you add lots of custom fonts.

Comment: Is there a way that a custom font can be directly used in xml, just like "sans","serif".