# How to apply custom font to every TextView in an Android app

Tags: android, fonts

I managed to include a custom font by creating an `assets/fonts` folder in my project and I am able to apply it to a `TextView` by creating a `Typeface` and applying it to the TextView.

But this method is exhausting because I must set an id property to every TextView, find each of them in every layout and apply the typeface to each of them.

Is there a clean way of doing this? Like with a style property that I could use in my xml layout files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an acceptable answer from Mark Phillip here : [How to change the font on the TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888508/how-to-change-the-font-on-the-textview#comment21603594_2888708)

> You actually can. You're creating a class that extends TextView and calls setTypeface from the constructor.