# How to format text for android app?

Tags: android, text-formatting

I'm trying to build an android app that displays a set of templates of cards (wedding cards, birthday cards etc) which can be customized as per user requirement. On selecting a template, i want the end user to fill out a form with basic details. I am trying to format the information fetched from user with different fonts, styles, colors, shapes ( like Word Art).
How should i do that ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textAppearance

Comment: also how to make themes to apply to textviews http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: Look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888508/how-to-change-the-font-on-the-textview

Comment: i want word-art like feature ..

Comment: with formating a text i mean ..i want the text in different shapes  floating, vertical view and i want to add this formatted text dynamically to a blank  image