# How to change the default font in an android app in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fonts

I would like to change the default font of the words in an android app with a java program.

Here is part of the code:

```
/**************************
 *
 * UI Display andMap Implementation method
 *
 **************************/

//The sorting method selection Spinner
private void setSpinner() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(getString(R.string.sort_suggested));
    list.add(getString(R.string.sort_price));
    list.add(getString(R.string.sort_duration));

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_layout, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_inner_layout);
    sortSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

How should I change the font on those list.add(getString....) comment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the font on the TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888508/how-to-change-the-font-on-the-textview)

Comment: Maybe this helps [How to Change Your Spinner Typeface](http://goo.gl/3Fj50A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exemple:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf");
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CustomFontText);
tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.