# how to make android application that supports indian languages .Like gujarati ,hindi

Tags: android

I want to make a quiz game application ..My mobile does not supports Gujarati language but I have an application that shows Gujarati fonts ..May be as image but I want to know how it can display Gujarat fonts in my mobile ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the font on the TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888508/how-to-change-the-font-on-the-textview)

Answer (score 2):

try to add font to assets/fonts and use it

```
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/GujaratiFont.ttf");
TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
myTextView.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```