# How to set Roboto variant font family to a Textview in android?

Tags: android, textview, android-xml, android-fonts

I have to add Roboto bold font style to my textview. How to implement that in android studio.

whether I have to add font family from externally or is there an option to add that internally?

I don't know what to do? Can you help me to solve this?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set custom font in .xml file instead of .java file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472953/how-to-set-custom-font-in-xml-file-instead-of-java-file)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to set a custom font for entire of application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-a-custom-font-for-entire-of-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any font family,We have to download that file(.ttf format) and add that file into our project directory.That too under the font directory.After adding those files,we can use that in our textview using `android:fontFamily` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Right from the Android [Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml)

To set a font for the TextView, In the layout XML file, set the fontFamily attribute to the font file you want to access.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"/>
```