# Automatically scale TextView text in RemoteView

Tags: java, android

I have a `TextView` that is used in a `RemoteView`. But the text in there varies and so sometimes it is simply too long and is partially cut off. I want my text to automatically scale so that it fits into the `TextView`. I am using the Support Library, but `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` won't work in a `RemoteView`. Is there another way?

Here's the xml-code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Some long text here."
        android:textSize="26sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a custom `TextView` as [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5535672/3145960).

I am not quite sure about auto resizing does not work with `RemoteView`. However, as shown in the [developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview) you might consider giving a specific height of the `TextView` in your case like the following.

```
<TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

You might also consider using `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView` for having the support for previous versions as long as you are using support library 26.0.0.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

You might check the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45762382/3145960) for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you can't use custom `Views` in `RemoteViews`. You also can't use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView`. And changing the height to a fixed value won't change anything either.