# Prevent text from wrapping into a new line in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, text

I am trying to display a textual histogram into a TextView in Android Studio but I don't want it to break the line of characters and separate them onto two lines, because it obviously ruins the histogram. I have the text set to resize itself in order to fit into the text box when I have more and more lines, but I want to make the size scale to the longest line specifically, that way they are all on a single line.

[Here is what the histogram is showing, rather than adjusting the line size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnbvB.png)

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/histogramTextbox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="453dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="80sp"
        android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
        android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/totalRollsText" />
```

Here is what I have in my textview XML in order to scale the font size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, you have to set `android:maxLines` too in order to get the autosizing to work properly (and it's a good idea to use `app:autoSize*` instead of `android:autoSize*` to support API levels < 26 or if you are using `AppCompat` components).

There are a lot of details about getting this right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64060439/9473786) - some key takeaways in addition to using `maxLines` are: do not use `android:singleLine`, and do not use `wrap_content` for either width or height.

**Demo Use**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/histogram_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
    android:maxLines="5"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="4dp"
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/get_text"/>
```

If the max lines changes dynamically, you can set it in code instead, like this

```kotlin
private fun expandHistogram() {
    var demoHist = "(01): #\n"
    demoHist += "(02): ##\n"
    demoHist += "(03): ##############\n"
    demoHist += "(04): " + "#".repeat(h) + "\n"
    demoHist += "(05): ##############\n"
    binding.histogramText.text = demoHist
    binding.histogramText.maxLines = 5
    h += 5
}
```

[image: Auto-sizing demo]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for this, I was able to solve my issue and it works great now. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Create constraintlayout as parent of a textview. Set your textview width to match constraint. You are good to go.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean by that. I have constraints set up for everything and I am unfamiliar with constraintLayout as an object in the XML. Do you have a link to something that might explain what you mean? I am fairly new to android studio and xml