# How can I make my TextView font as shown in image

Tags: android, layout, text, textview

I am trying to style my text of **STUDENT LOGIN** which is shown in the image.
But I don't know how can use a different custom font to make my **STUDENT LOGIN** to look like as shown in the image.

I want Style in that way. How Can I make my S and L shown in image

[image: Student Login Image with customized font]

Comment: Did you try googling *"fonts for android"*? Go through different fonts and download whichever ones you need.

Comment: refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9820211/5148289)

Answer (score 2):

First of all set your font to the `TextView`

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font/myFont.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

Now, You can achieve different size of `S` and `T` using `SpannableString`

```
String s = "STUDENT LOGIN";
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(s);
ss.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0, 1, 0);       // Set Size
ss.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 8, 9, 0);       // Set Size
textView.setText(ss);
```

Here replace `2f` according to size you want.

`0` is starting index of `S` and `1` is ending index.

`8` is starting index of `L` and `9` is ending index.

Answer (score 1):

Find font family then Get it font yourfont.ttf  file from internet and paste into assets folder in android.

Then apply your Textview

```
Typeface customTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font/custum_font.ttf");
myTextView.setTypeface(customTypeface);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use default font and want to use different font without hassle, just use [this](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) library. You can apply custom font to whole app or particular TextView.

Example for specific TextView :

```
<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"/>
```

Follow the instruction from read me file and you will get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use spannable you can use this :

```
String sourceString = "<b>" + id + "</b> " + name; 
mytextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(sourceString));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple HTML tags in your strings. You can do the following:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>S</b>tudent <b>L</b>ogin"));
```

This way S and L will become bold, while all other chars will be regular.