# Error trying to change font android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, fonts, compiler-errors

I am trying to change the font of a TextView programatically in android studio, ive followed some tutorials closely but it keeps giving me errors and was just wondering if anyone has any ideas?

**Examples of questions I followed:**

1. [Android develop LCD font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878882/android-develop-lcd-font/2880348#2880348)
2. [How to change the font on the TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888508/how-to-change-the-font-on-the-textview)

**TextView:**

```
TextView
android:id="@+id/settingsTitle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Settings"
android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"/>
```

**Code that changes font:**

```
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Stocky.ttf");
TextView settingsTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settingsTitle);
settingsTitle.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

**Error log:**

```
Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file
Function: selinux_android_load_priority [1], There is no sepolicy version file
Function: selinux_android_load_priority , loading version is VE=SEPF_GT-I9507_4.3_0016
selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts
```

Comment: The lines you have posted that is your "error log" has nothing to do with your app. Please explain what "keeps giving me errors" means.

Comment: where you have placed font files?

Comment: the logcat spits out those errors, im sorry if they are not relevant I wasn't sure, also my font file is in an assets folder that is in src/main

Comment: Also by keep giving me errors, I mean the entire activity wont load, it just goes to a black screen, at the moment that TextView is the only thing in the activity so it cant really be much else causing this.

Comment: have you set content view of your activity and also try to set textColor white to your textview

Comment: Run in on non-selinux device and tell

Comment: Post the correct log cat error , re run your activity and when it crash choose error in logcat and post all the red lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't working because I was doing the code part in the onCreate, even though i was actually using fragments, so I just deleted the fragment and went back to using the normal activity and its working now.

thanks for the help.