# Error trying change font in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm starting in Android development and I got myself stocked in a problem...

I am trying to change the font of a Button in Android Studio, I've followed some tutorials closely but it didn't work.

**Tutorials I followed:**

[Error trying to change font android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31676566/error-trying-to-change-font-android-studio)

[How to change the font on the TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888508/how-to-change-the-font-on-the-textview)

I don't receive any error message, it just doesn't work. Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong?

**Code:**

```
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/jua.ttf");

    Button Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button)
    Button.setTypeface(font);
```

**XML:**

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/my_button_bg"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
```

**Image of structure of folders:**
[Structure of folder - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taiyh.jpg)

Comment: in latest android studio there is a separate folder for fonts in which you can define your custom fonts  and add to the textview or button by setting font-family there

Comment: I'd recommend you the Calligraphy library to deal with the fonts. Its pretty easy to use and also lightweight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried inserting your font in res/font directory and loading it as @font/myfont or R.font.myfont.

API 26 introduced this feature and you can find complete guide here: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml